# Calling web services consumer from XPages

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes

I had an XPage project where I needed to call some web services to get some information, How can i call or import the web service consumer in my java class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "ready-built" design element to you when you are working in XPages and that JVM.

However, you have plenty of possibilities as this is Java :-)

You can simply use the URL object:

```
URL url = new URL("http://.....");
InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

... and then you can use the InputStream to read the result from the service. How you do this is really quite dependent on the service.

I call services where I read JSON - and process that either using the JSON objects already coming with XPages, like:

```
JsonJavaFactory factory = JsonJavaFactory.instanceEx;
Object jsonObjs;
String url = ConfigurationBean.getCurrentInstance().getUrlWebserviceLakes();
jsonObjs = JsonParser.fromJson(factory, new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url).openStream())));
for (Iterator<Object> val = factory.iterateArrayValues(jsonObjs); val.hasNext();) {
    JsonJavaObject obj = (JsonJavaObject) val.next();
    Double idNum = (Double) obj.getJsonProperty("id");
```

Or you could start down the interesting and very strong path of adding other frameworks as OSGi plugins, like [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). The same actually goes for e.g. [Apache HttpComponents HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) should the built in support of the URL class not be sufficient.

If you want to know how to wrap existing jars into OSGi plugins then I have written a [couple of articles](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/wrap-an-existing-jar-file-into-a-plug-in/) about that ;-)

/John